# CRM 2011 Upgradation Date

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I need to know that when my **CRM-11** Online is scheduled for **CRM-13** Update?

Although I was getting a yellow bar notification but currently not getting anymore  notification on my homepage.

I tried to rescheduled now but finally got an error and that notification is not coming more..

Does this reflect after 24 hours??

Also i am not getting this option in "Administrative" section as well..

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is by default, I guess..r8??

There is an option to delay your update.

Although i have tried this but now not able to see that date.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Administration

Strangely it seems to be in the "Resources In Use" Section.

In there you should be able to see your "Primary Update date" and Secondary update date.

[image: Resources In Use]

You can click on the "Reschedule Update" to move the date (The date must be between now and February)

If you get an error connecting to the Resources In Use page OR when you click Reschedule update (which is sounds like you are) then you will need to contact Microsoft to change the date. We had the same issue and had to request they fix the issue for us.

Comment: Hi Campey,

Thanks to give your idea but i am not getting any option for "Primary Update date" or "Secondary update date".

Now according to your suggestion i should contact Microsoft..

If i will find anything, will come back here..

Comment: Yes, after contacting with Microsoft, we are able to see our Upgradation date now.